# com.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication won't run unless you update Google Play services

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to make a button (in my case, ImageButton) which will spot user's location on the Google Map. I've done this so far and when I press the button in the application simulator shows; "com.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication won't run unless you update Google Play services". Here is my code:

**built.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.konarx.a11042016"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
}
```

**MapsActivity.class**

```
package com.example.konarx.a11042016;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends MainScreen implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Comment: compilesdk 25 and targetsdk 25 ... try this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just faced the same problem.

In your build.gradle, downgrade the version of play services to 9.6.0

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Tried it and gets me an error (red underline) when I sync after the change I make. Thanks for your answer though...

Answer (score 2):

I was using Nougat (API 25) when this happened to me. Using a different API package (I ended up using Marshmallow API 23 on a new emulator) fixed it for me.  I was using play services version 10.0.1 in my project, and downgrading my play services version wasn't an option since Firebase required 10.0.1.